# Moses at fault for spies?

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, tanach, moshe-rabbeinu, pentateuch-chumash

Looking to better understand if, per the sources, Moses was at fault for sending spies, especially as it relates to sending them on a seemingly military mission.

Comment: The mission was itself a direct order from Hashem: וידבר ה' אל משה לאמר שלח לך אנשים ויתרו את ארץ כנען _The Lord spoke to Moshe saying, Send out for yourself men and they will scout the Land of Canaan..._ (Bamidbar 13:1-2)

Comment: @Yehuda, see Gershon's answer, that it was not "a direct order" from Hashem.

Comment: @Meir Rashi and Ramban very specifically say it was not, but see my posted answer that indicates the Kli Yakar infers that it is.

Comment: This question would be a lot better if it would include which spy mission of Moses's it's referring to: Numbers 21:32 or Numbers 13. Or do you mean both?

Comment: Numbers 13 primarily - thanks for probing questions

Comment: Moses was at fault? G-d told him to send the spies.

Comment: Abarbanel says Moshe was at fault for adding on to the command to send the spies. Moshe added that they should report on the quality of the land, etc, which led to the whole episode. This is why Moshe was published with not entering the land of Israel. If I have time I'll wrote this as an answer.

Comment: The Michtav Mei'Eliyahu has a brilliant analysis of this question, but too long to summarize here.

Comment: Rashi to [Devarim 1:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.1.23?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he) says Moshe acquiesced to the Jews' demand in order to demonstrate confidence, not expecting them to actually take him up on the offer. He considered them to be at fault for their lack of faith.

Answer (score 1):

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Numbers.13.2.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) - says that according to your own judgement: I do not command you, but if you wish to do so send them.

> שלח לך. לְדַעְתְּךָ, אֲנִי אֵינִי מְצַוֶּה לְךָ, אִם תִּרְצֶה שְׁלַח;
> לְפִי שֶׁבָּאוּ יִשְׂרָאֵל וְאָמְרוּ נִשְׁלְחָה אֲנָשִׁים לְפָנֵינוּ,
> כְּמָה שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר "וַתִּקְרְבוּן אֵלַי כֻּלְּכֶם" וְגוֹ'

[Ramban](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=154) says that based on Rashi it would seem that Moshe sinned by sending the Meraglim. However at the end the Ramban says it was not a sin on Moshe's part as Hashem said he may send them.

Comment: But that doesn't really answer the question of whether he's at fault for doing so.

Comment: @Meir The Ramban suggests that Moshe was not at fault.

Answer (score 0):

The mission was itself a direct order from Hashem: וידבר ה' אל משה לאמר שלח לך אנשים ויתרו את ארץ כנען *The Lord spoke to Moshe saying, Send out for yourself men and they will scout the Land of Canaan...* (Bamidbar 13:1-2) In fact, the Kli Yakar says that לך means for *Moshe's* benefit:

> לפי שאמרו ישראל (דברים א כב) נשלחה לפנינו אנשים ויחפרו לנו את הארץ. לנו היינו להנאתנו ולטובתינו, ואמר הקב"ה למשה שלח לך, ולא להם כי לך דווקא יהיה השליחות להנאה ולטובה אבל להם לא יהיה השליחות לטובתם כי ע"י שליחות זה נגזרה עליהם מיתה ולמשה גרם שיהיה חי עוד מ' שנה, כי כבר נגזר על משה שלא יראה את העשוי למלכי ז' אומות וע"י חטא המרגלים נשתהו מ' שנה
>
> Since Israel said (Devarim 1:22) "We will send before us men and they will search out the Land for us": *For us* is *for our benefit and for our good*, and G-d said to Moshe "Send for you," and not for them because specifically *for you* will the mission be a benefit and a good; but not for them, because through this mission death will be decreed upon them and Moshe would incidentally live 40 more years (because it had already been decreed on Moshe that he would not witness what would happen to the kings of the Seven Nations, and through the Spies they would wait 40 years).

While [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.13.2?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Numbers.13.2.2&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=he) explicitly says that לך means that this was *not* a commandment from Hashem and Moshe was therefore acting of his own accord, Kli Yakar's usage of לך for a different purpose suggests that he does not agree with this perspective. The inference that is it was a commandment in the full sense of the word, and that, although the benefit is incidental (see K"Y above), the mission still benefited Moshe rather than faulted him.

Answer (score 0):

The [Ohr Hachaim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.13.2?lang=he&with=Or%20HaChaim&lang2=he) offers two possibilities why not to fault Moshe for the debacle of the spies.

1. Moshe innocently thought that they were on an mission to find hidden treasures in Eretz Canaan and had no idea what the spies true intentions were.
2. Moshe knew very well what the spies intended to do but since Hashem allowed them to proceed, it wasn't his place to "outsmart Hashem" and prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

One explanation given in the Rishonim is that Moshe saw which way  the winds were blowing...

The  Sifre says they came "Barvuviya"; an unruly crowd with  the younger people pushing the older ones etc. to ask about sending spies. Looking at the situation he realized that they weren't really committed to going to Eretz Yisroel  and  were actually looking for some excuse to delay or get out of it.

He felt that is would be better if they refused to go to Eretz Yisroel because of a bad report given by the spies (which was sure to be coming) than they find some  non excuse as  the latter option  would make them  much more guilty.

Another explanation (or observation) givin in the Rishonim is that they were  never told to be **MERAGLIM**. In Parshas Shelach it says  שְׁלַח לְךָ֣ אֲנָשִׁ֗ים ***וְיָתֻ֨רוּ֙*** אֶת־אֶ֣רֶץ כְּנַ֔עַן . The entire Parshas Shelach only uses the word  יָתֻ֨רוּ֙ or some variation of it when describing their mission.

The word יָתֻ֨רוּ֙ in Tanach is used for looking for the good and the way to set it up. Meragal implies spying for the weakness  of a place. Moshe told them to do the former. They choose to do the lattar

Answer (score 0):

In Michtav Mei'Eliyahu, vol. 1 p.187, [R' Dessler][1] has an absolutely brilliant analysis explaining the mistake of Moshe and the Jewish people in sending spies. I can't do it justice here, but he says (based on Rashi that Hashem said שלח לך לדעתך) that Moshe was tested as to the line between necessary and unnecessary hishtadlus.
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliyahu_Eliezer_Dessler